# Windows 7 hangs at Logoff

Tags: windows-7, freeze, logoff

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate Notebook (Acer 1420p - PDC edition) that sometimes hangs at the "Logging off..." screen.

The Eventlog has the following entries:

- 18:13:51 Warning: The winlogon notification subscriber Profiles is taking long time to handle the notification event (Logoff).
- 18:12:51 Information: The winlogon notification subscriber SessionEnv was unavailable to handle a notification event.
- 18:12:51 Information: The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code (0x40010004)

The machine has all Windows Update fixes installed. I am unable to reproduce the problem immediately after startup but it will happen if the machine is running for some time (with suspends/hibernate).

Any ideas on what's the problem or how I could diagnose it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that the Live Mesh client is to blame. (workaround: exit before logging off)

Comment: You can create a scheduled task to exectue at log off in the Task scheduler that will kill the Live Mesh process.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external harddrive attached? For some reason, my rig hangs on shutdown if I do not disconnect my drive. It'll immediately continue the process once I do though. Weird bug and worth trying if you have a USB EHDD.

Comment: No, no harddisk. Nothing else is attached either.